# How to set the revision Number to a file

Tags: c#, file, numbers, revision

I am using the file upload in my project. I like to set the revision number for the file which I am uploading in the database. i.e. I will upload a sd.doc file for first time it will be saved as version 1. After I am downloading that file I will make some changes and I will save that it should be saved as version 2. While viewing it should show both the version and I should choose the file based on the version. Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It sounds like you have solved the issue, you just need to go and implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of your question. You are saving your file in a database field right? When you say "While viewing", what do you mean, by what way do you "view"? Can't you add a column to your database containing the version number?

Answer (score 1):

If I right understand your problem, you need versioning system for docs. 
One of the solutions that I can think off, is using of [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) DVS. You can create simple UI interafce to interact with it's command line "hg". It provides to you a huge potential, that most probabbly you will no need in your app, but saving "revision" number, enable others to query it, all this is already done +  you will given huge amount of options for future development.

But all depends on your project requirements. Keep an eye on that and make a choice.

Hope this helps.

Regards.